# Problem with eclipse internet explorer browser (help system & other)

Tags: java, eclipse, browser

Does not show any pictures [only boxes with text]. Tried to reinstall IE, it didn't help.
Actually I have IE 7. Version of Eclipse is Galileo.
Should say, IE works fine if used independently.

As Von.C recommended, I tried to open the content in an external browser (Firefox).
It looks the same. Boxes with the text.

http://img62.imageshack.us/img62/7712/erronouseclipse.jpg - internal browser

http://img687.imageshack.us/img687/9915/erronousopera.png - external Opera

As far as I can see, no errors in the log.

What would you say?

Answer (score 0):

What your error logs mention?

Following [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.webtools/msg12817.html), here is a couple of suggestions:

> Have you tried changing eclipse browser settings? (Under `Window -> Preferences -> Web Browser`)
>   Try picking something other than "Internal Web Browser" and relaunch eclipse.
>   Now when you launch WSE it should come up in an external browser right from the start.

(note sure if the following applies in your case, but I mention it just in case)

> Another thing I noticed from your URL is that you have cookies disabled in your browser. I tried disabling cookies also but I could not reproduce your problem, but maybe you can try enabling cookies and see if that changes the behavior.

Comment: @Von.C Imagine! The same thing in an external browser! Boxes with the text!